# collection of derived class

Tags: c#, collections, derived-class

I’m refactoring my code of separation of concern (SoC). Move non-AutoCAD code away to separate dll, so Common, Data Access, web service, AutoCAD related, … in different dll files.

Here is sample of my class:

```
// non-AutoCAD dll
public class Loc
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    ...
}

// AutoCAD dll
public class AcadLoc : Loc
{
    public ObjectId oid;
}

// non-AutoCAD dll
public class Locs : List<Loc>
{
    public Loc Get_By_Id(long id)
    {
        return this.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Id == id);
    }
}

// AutoCAD dll
public class AcadLocs : Locs // or List<AcadLoc> ? 
{
}
```

My question is, can I run something like

```
AcadLocs myAcadLocs = new AcadLocs();
AcadLoc myAcadLoc = myAcadLocs.Get_By_Id(1);   // How to make this works?
```

I tried:

```
public class AcadLocs : Locs // or List<AcadLoc> ? 
{
    public AcadLoc Get_By_Id(int id)
    {
        return this.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Id == id);
    }
}
```

it would not works.

Now I change to this:

```
public interface ILocData<T> where T : new() {} 

// non-AutoCAD dll
public class Loc : ILocData<Loc>
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    ...
}

// AutoCAD dll
public class AcadLoc : Loc, ILocData<AcadLoc>
{
    public ObjectId oid;
}

public class LocDataCollection<T, TCollection> : List<T>
    where T : ILocData<T>, new()
    where TCollection : LocDataCollection<T, TCollection>, new()
{
}

// non-AutoCAD dll
public class Locs : LocDataCollection<Loc, Locs>
{
    public Loc Get_By_Id(int id)
    {
        return this.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Id == id);
    }

    public bool Check()
    {
        foreach (Loc loc in this)
        {
        ....
        }
    }
}

// AutoCAD dll  
public class AcadLocs : LocDataCollection<AcadLoc, AcadLocs>
{
    public AcadLoc Get_By_Id(int id)
    {
        return this.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Now,

```
AcadLoc myAcadLoc = myAcadLocs.Get_By_Id(1);   // works
```

but

```
myAcadLocs.Check();  // failed
```

Thanks

Wes

Comment: "// failed" -- how?  How can we answer your question without you telling us what the failure is?

Comment: I got compile error message: 'AcadLocs' does not contain a definition for 'Check' and no extension method 'Check' accepting a first argument of type 'AcadLocs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is extension method

```
public static class MyExtension 

{
    public static Loc Get_By_Id(this Locs l,int id) 
    {
        return l.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Id == id);
    }

    public static bool Check(this Locs l)
    {
        foreach (Loc loc in l)
        {
        ....
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have this code in place then just call this methods like this

```
 myAcadLocs.Get_By_Id(1);
 myAcadLocs.Check();
 myLocs.Get_By_Id(1);
 myLocs.Check();
```

Answer (score 1):

I refer to your first attempt.

### 1. Inheritance

```
public class AcadLocs : Locs // or List<AcadLoc> ?
```

If you want to derive from `Locs` or `List<AcadLoc>` depends on how you want to use this class. If you want to declare common members or if it is necessary that you can assign an instance of `AcadLocs` to a variable of type `Locs` like this

```
Locs locs = new AcadLocs();
```

then you surely need to derive from `Locs`.

### 2. Get_By_Id

For this method I would use the `OfType<>` method like this:

```
public class AcadLocs : Locs // or List<AcadLoc> ? 
{
    public AcadLoc Get_By_Id(int id)
    {
        return this.OfType<AcadLoc>().SingleOrDefault(n => n.Id == id);
    }
}
```

`OfType<AcadLoc>` creates an `IEnumeralbe<AcadLoc>` out of the existing sequence selecting only elements that are of the specified type (`AcadLoc`). This will help you with your `Check` method, too.